# Stop aborting previous observable by triggering a new one

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I came up with the following task:

- I have 5 text-input fields
- These fields are all connected with a `subject.next()` function on `keyup`.
- On every input text change a request to my server is send - yea, this behavior is for all 5 input fields.

My problem is:

- If I enter text in these fields to fast with a fast switch on the input objects, the previous request, which might not be finished, will be discarded.
- That seems to be happen during the long `switchMap` server request (see below)

**My HTML looks like:**

```
<div *ngFor='let model of models'>
    <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='model.text' (ngModelChange)='mySubject.next(model)' />
    <div [class.succeeded]='model.valid'></div>
</div>
```

**And my .ts component:**

```
mySubject = new Subject<any>();

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.mySubject
       .debounceTime(200)
       .do(item => item.valid = false)
       .switchMap(item => this.myHttpService.check(item), (item, exists) => {
           item.valid = exists;
           return item;
       })
       .subscribe(...);
}
```

Is there any possibility to wait for the previous observable to finish or to execute them simultaneously?

Comment: Use `mergeMap` instead of `switchMap`

Comment: thanks, that works like a charm!